# If there's a grouping function for the diversity, is there one for evenness?

Tags: grouping, vegan

I have some species tables, that I am attempting to get diversity indices from.
I have used:

```
> diversity (nta[,c(-1,-2)], groups = nta$Quadrant)
> specno (nta [,c(-1,-2)], groups = nta$Quadrant)
```

to group abundance and H' by quadrant.

Would there be a way to do this for Pielou's evenness?
Here is the code I have used to calculate it:

```
> naS<- apply (nta[,c(-1,-2)]>0,1,sum) 
> diversity (nta[,c(-1,-2)])/log(naS)
```

But I am unsure where to put a grouping function in the code, and everywhere I've tried R hasn't liked.

**note - this is far from essential & while I can do the same thing in excel, I would like to improve my python skill.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about **R** (not python) package **vegan**: It does not directly implement Pielou's evenness, but it can be calculated as a ratio of Shannon-Weaver `diversity` and log number of species (`specnumber`). In **vegan** both of these have the same `groups` argument, and if you use it for both similarly, you get what you asked for. That is, diversity of SUs accumulated by `groups`, and species number of SUs accumulated by `groups`.

Comment: I am aware of this, and as for Pielou's evenness it is H' divided by the potential maximum of H'; or H' to the log of the species number.
To calculate this in R I used:
> naS<- apply (nta[,c(-1,-2)]>0,1,sum) 
> diversity (nta[,c(-1,-2)])/log(naS)
do you know of a way to affix a grouping argument to this code?  Would such an argument need to be in both lines of code?

Thank you for your help, Dr. Oksanen

Comment: Look how this is done in vegan functions `diversity` and `specnumber` and shamelessly copy the code (as allowed by GPL2).

Comment: That took be longer than I'd like to admit but we got there. Thanks again Dr. Oksanen.

There's a couple more things that I'd like to pick your brain about unrelated to the question if you wouldn't mind?